# Ruby: Remove new lines, carriage returns from text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a text string such as this, and I need to remove all the carriage returns and backslashes.

> An Ox came down to a reedy pool to drink. As he splashed heavily into
>   the water, he crushed a young Frog into the mud.\r\n\r\nThe old Frog
>   soon missed the little one and asked his brothers and sisters what had
>   become of him.\r\n\r\n\"A great big monster,\" said one of them,
>   \"stepped on little brother with one of his huge feet!\"\r\n\r\n\"Big,
>   was he!\" said the old Frog, puffing herself up. \"Was he as big as
>   this?\"\r\n\r\n\"Oh, much bigger!\" they cried.\r\n\r\nThe Frog puffed
>   up still more.\r\n\r\n\"He could not have been bigger than this,\" she
>   said. But the little Frogs all declared that the monster was much,
>   much bigger and the old Frog kept puffing herself out more and more
>   until, all at once, she burst.\r\n

I tried this, but this still leaves out the the backslashes.

```
text.gsub(/\r?\n|\r/, "")
```

> "An Ox came down to a reedy pool to drink. As he splashed heavily into
>   the water, he crushed a young Frog into the mud.  The old Frog soon
>   missed the little one and asked his brothers and sisters what had
>   become of him.  \"A great big monster,\" said one of them, \"stepped
>   on little brother with one of his huge feet!\"  \"Big, was he!\" said
>   the old Frog, puffing herself up. \"Was he as big as this?\"  \"Oh,
>   much bigger!\" they cried.  The Frog puffed up still more.  \"He could
>   not have been bigger than this,\" she said. But the little Frogs all
>   declared that the monster was much, much bigger and the old Frog kept
>   puffing herself out more and more until, all at once, she burst. "

The following expression seems to match the correct pattern at [www.rubular.com](http://rubular.com) including the individual backslashes, but does not seem to work in my console (Ruby 2.2.1)

```
text.gsub(/(\\r\\n)|\\/, "")
```

Note: For full disclosure, this string of text is captured in an HTML editor and stored into a database column. I have a need to strip out the HTML characters and I use the following -

```
text = ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(page.content).gsub(/\r?\n|\r\\|\\/, "")
```

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: What about `text.gsub(/\R+|\//, '')`? However, the escape symbols are most likely to be missing in your actual input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew those are _not actual backslashes_. It’s how ruby’s `puts` outputs double quotes.

Comment: That still returns with a backslash

Comment: Yes, `/\R+/` is enough :)

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether the characters `\\ ` and `r` are in your string, or if they are (as your title suggests) actual carriage return characters. It's also not clear whether your string is wrapped in double-quote characters (`"`) or if those are denoting the string in Ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa: BTW, it all depends on how this text is declared. With single quoted literals, the backslashes are preserved.

Comment: @coreyward - I edited my question above to describe how I capture the text. The \\ and r are in the text string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Yes, that definitely seems shorter, but I cannot seem to take off the single backslashes that appear in the string.

Comment: Please post the *code* to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - The code towards the end of my edited question is all I am using. page.content is actual string that is in blockquotes above.

Comment: would this work (\\r)|(\\n)|(\\) ? I tried it with your passage on [this website](https://regex101.com/) and worked fine for me.

Comment: Look at http://ideone.com/YnATOP, there are *no* escape symbols if the string literal is double-quoted.

Comment: @mudasobwa `puts` will actually just show the quotes, but `p` (or `puts str.inspect`) will show the quotes escaped (i.e. with backslashes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient way to perform this operation is with [`String#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-delete) (or `#delete!`):

```
text.delete!("\r\n\\")
p text
puts
puts text
```

Output:

> "An Ox came down to a reedy pool to drink. As he splashed heavily into
>   the water, he crushed a young Frog into the mud.The old Frog soon
>   missed the little one and asked his brothers and sisters what had
>   become of him.\"A great big monster,\" said one of them, \"stepped on
>   little brother with one of his huge feet!\"\"Big, was he!\" said the
>   old Frog, puffing herself up. \"Was he as big as this?\"\"Oh, much
>   bigger!\" they cried.The Frog puffed up still more.\"He could not have
>   been bigger than this,\" she said. But the little Frogs all declared
>   that the monster was much, much bigger and the old Frog kept puffing
>   herself out more and more until, all at once, she burst."
>
> An Ox came
>   down to a reedy pool to drink. As he splashed heavily into the water,
>   he crushed a young Frog into the mud.The old Frog soon missed the
>   little one and asked his brothers and sisters what had become of
>   him."A great big monster," said one of them, "stepped on little
>   brother with one of his huge feet!""Big, was he!" said the old Frog,
>   puffing herself up. "Was he as big as this?""Oh, much bigger!" they
>   cried.The Frog puffed up still more."He could not have been bigger
>   than this," she said. But the little Frogs all declared that the
>   monster was much, much bigger and the old Frog kept puffing herself
>   out more and more until, all at once, she burst.

Benchmark results:

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
         String#gsub     2.826k i/100ms
           String#tr    35.794k i/100ms
       String#delete    37.147k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
         String#gsub     29.801k (± 2.8%) i/s -    149.778k in   5.030044s
           String#tr    399.391k (± 3.3%) i/s -      2.004M in   5.024297s
       String#delete    411.065k (± 4.0%) i/s -      2.080M in   5.068783s
```

I used `/\R+|\//` for the String#gsub method.